# JAVA_HOME not appearing and MAVEN_HOME is not set correctly

Tags: java, maven, path, java-home

I installed OpenJDK 12 by adding the /bin to the PATH and making a JAVA_HOME without the /bin.

Proof that this works :

```
  C:\Users\rakoo>java -version
  openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

  C:\Users\rakoo>javac -version
  javac 12.0.1

  C:\Users\rakoo>echo %JAVA_HOME%
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
```

The problem is what I get when I type mvn -v in cmd.

```
 Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04- 
 04T21:00:29+02:00)
 Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
 Java version: 12.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program 
 Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

As you can see, there is no "Java home: " and the maven home is set incorrectly. I made system variable called MAVEN_HOME with the value set to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1.

Proof that MAVEN_HOME is set:

```
C:\Users\rakoo>echo %MAVEN_HOME%
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1
```

[Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/r2qW2HG) of my Path and system variables.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: maven just get java from environmental variable . MVN -V does show java runtime but it doesnot show %JAVA_HOME% in mvn -v commnad

Comment: add mvn and java in path variable as %JAVA_HOME%\bin and %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed On the Maven [website](https://maven.apache.org/install.html), mvn -v shows Java home.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed I tried that and still have the same problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TIuJz1U here is my screenshot of mvn -v . it doesnot show JAVA_HOME also . but for me maven is working perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maven version 3.6.1 they have removed the "JAVA HOME" property from maven output for the version command(`mvn -v`) but that should not pose any problem as such. You can refer to CLIReportingUtils.showVersion() method in below link:

https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIReportingUtils.java

```
public static String showVersion()
{
    final String ls = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
    Properties properties = getBuildProperties();
    StringBuilder version = new StringBuilder( 256 );
    version.append( buffer().strong( createMavenVersionString( properties ) ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( reduce(
        properties.getProperty( "distributionShortName" ) + " home: " + System.getProperty( "maven.home",
                                                                                            "<unknown Maven "
                                                                                                + "home>" ) ) )
        .append( ls );
    version.append( "Java version: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.version", "<unknown Java version>" ) ).append( ", vendor: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.vendor", "<unknown vendor>" ) ).append( ", runtime: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "java.home", "<unknown runtime>" ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( "Default locale: " ).append( Locale.getDefault() ).append( ", platform encoding: " ).append(
        System.getProperty( "file.encoding", "<unknown encoding>" ) ).append( ls );
    version.append( "OS name: \"" ).append( Os.OS_NAME ).append( "\", version: \"" ).append( Os.OS_VERSION ).append(
        "\", arch: \"" ).append( Os.OS_ARCH ).append( "\", family: \"" ).append( Os.OS_FAMILY ).append( '\"' );
    return version.toString();
}
```

Comment: Maven works perfectly for me. I was just worried because it didnt show, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has 2 parts:

1. **"the maven home is set incorrectly"** - No. It's not.

Output of command `mvn -v` shows MAVEN HOME as `Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..`. Notice the **..** at the end. It means 1 dir up from current level i.e. bin, which effectively equals  `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1` which is what you have set.

2. **there is no "Java home: "** - the maven output does not always shows the JAVA home. So it should not be a problem.

Also I see incorrect path of java runtime. Have you checked your jdk folder. Has been correctly downloaded? Does it contain jre folder?
In my case runtime value shows:  `<...>/jdk_1.8/jre`

**EDIT:**

As per [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9ualdq/why_did_java_11_jre_not_install_with_jdk_and/), a separate JRE has been removed JDK 11 onwards. Also, see below screenshot. In the upper half  (above red line) , java is set to jdk 12 (downloaded from link provided by you), and still JAVA_HOME is visible in `mvn -v` output. Only difference I see is that your maven version is different. Can you try once with maven 3.5.3?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying! It doesn't have a jre folder. I tried downloading JDK 12 from this [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html), but there is still no jre folder.

Comment: I checked this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/9ualdq/why_did_java_11_jre_not_install_with_jdk_and/ and it mentions that a separate jre has been removed from jdk 11 onwards. Also, Oracle jdk has moved from free license to paid license. Based on your requirement, you can choose openJdk (it too doesn't have separate JRE, I guess)